# PDO much slower than MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here's how I've set up

```
class Core
{
    public $dbh;
    private static $instance;
    private function __construct()
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . CoreConfig::read('db.host') .
               ';dbname='    . CoreConfig::read('db.basename') .
               ';port='      . CoreConfig::read('db.port') .
               ';connect_timeout=15';            
        $user = CoreConfig::read('db.user');             
        $password = CoreConfig::read('db.password');
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}


class CoreConfig
{
    static $confArray;

    public static function read($name)
    {
        return self::$confArray[$name];
    }

    public static function write($name, $value)
    {
        self::$confArray[$name] = $value;
    }

}
```

**Include File:** db.php

```
CoreConfig::write('db.host', SERVER);
CoreConfig::write('db.port', '3306');
CoreConfig::write('db.basename', DB);
CoreConfig::write('db.user', USER);
CoreConfig::write('db.password', PASSWORD);
```

Now I'm trying to convert my site from using MySQL to PDO. However, after reviewing some of my queries and page loading time, I've found that my queries are a lot slower. Here's a simplified example of how I used to use MySQL in one of my classes:

**MySQL Version**

```
class lotInfo
{
    protected $_lot;
    public function __construct($lot)
    {
        $this->_lot = $lot;
    }

    public function numJobsMil()
    {

        $JOB_IDS = array();
        $SQL = mysql_query("SELECT job_id FROM job_materials_lot WHERE lot='".$this->_lot."'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($SQL))
        {
            array_push($JOB_IDS,$data['job_id']);
        }

        $SQL2 = mysql_query("SELECT job_id FROM job_materials_prop WHERE lot='".$this->_lot."'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($data2=mysql_fetch_array($SQL))
        {
            array_push($JOB_IDS,$data2['job_id']);
        }       

        return $JOB_IDS;
    }

}
```

When calling the method from within a loop on my page, the data loads in 0.6 seconds. For example:

```
require_once 'db.php'
$lots = array("SIB","ABC","DEF","ZSP"); // etc etc etc
foreach($lots as $x => $lot)
{
    $info = new lotInfo($lot);
    $jobs[] = $info->numJobsMil();  
}
// do stuff
```

Now, the PDO version of my class as follows:

**PDO Version:**

```
class lotInfo
{
    protected $_lot;
    protected $_pdo;
    public function __construct($lot)
    {
        $core = Core::getInstance();
        $this->_pdo = $core;    
        $this->_lot = $lot;
    }

    public function numJobsMil()
    {

        $JOB_IDS = array();
        $STH  = $this->_pdo->dbh->query("SELECT job_id FROM job_materials_lot WHERE lot='".$this->_lot."'");
        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $SQL = mysql_query("SELECT job_id FROM job_materials_lot WHERE lot='".$this->_lot."'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($data = $STH->fetch())
        {
            array_push($JOB_IDS,$data['job_id']);
        }

        $STH_sub  = $this->_pdo->dbh->query("SELECT job_id FROM job_materials_prop WHERE lot='".$this->_lot."'");
        while($sub_data = $STH_sub->fetch())
        {
            array_push($JOB_IDS,$sub_data['job_id']);
        }   

        return $JOB_IDS;
    }

}
```

So far, this works perfectly, however when running this through the same loop, the data loads on average of 3.6 seconds whenever a user accesses the page. Now, I'm not sure why this is happening, but I'd like to get some opinions on this.

Comment: You are actually mixing mysql and PDO. this requires two parallel connections being open

Comment: Where do you see the mix?

Comment: Your PDO version should probably not have `mysql_query` in the middle of it (`numJobsMil()`).

Comment: Goodness you're right.....

Comment: And it's worth using prepared statements if you're using PDO

Comment: You're also executing an additional query in the PDO: `"SELECT job_id FROM job_materials_lot WHERE lot='".$this->_lot."'");` twice

Comment: Yea I noticed that as well. The re-writing process is quite difficult since forgetting old code (like this) can cause many conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most PDO way to achieve the same (also taking advantage of `UNION` to aggregate the results within the database layer):

```
public function numJobsMil()
{
    $STH = $this->_pdo->dbh->prepare('
      SELECT job_id FROM job_materials_lot  WHERE lot = ?
    UNION ALL
      SELECT job_id FROM job_materials_prop WHERE lot = ?
    ');

    $STH->execute([$this->_lot, $this->_lot]);
    return $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
}
```

Whenever I see `UNION` used in this way, I cannot help but wonder whether the two tables ought to be combined, with a column to flag from which table the underlying records originated.

Comment: I've thought about combining both tables but haven't figured out a way to organize the data. However, the UNION would seem ideal in this case.